# Restricting AMI's to VPC for launching an EC2 Instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have two VPC's in my account. We are restricting EC2 AMI's to selected list of AMI's by using an IAM policy. Here is the Policy.
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-12ab3456",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-34de5678"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Now I want to have this restriction for only one VPC. For other VPC, I don't want have any restrictions on AMI's. I made following changes to IAM policy to achieve this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2RunInstanceForVPC2",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-1a2bcd34",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:placement-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2RunInstanceForVPC1",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-a1bc23d4",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-12ab3456",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-34de5678"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is not working.Can someone help me with IAM policy to achieve this permissions.

Regards,
Veeresham

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user having EC2 full access. you can add the additional custom policy to restrict one VPC for specified AMI ids.

Here is the custom IAM policy to restrict AMI in specified a VPC:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:image/AMIID1",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:image/AMIID2"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:vpc/RESTRICTED_VPCID"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:security-group/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: In the above policy,you need to change the below things.

- **REGION** is AWS Region
- **ACCOUNTNUMBER** is AWS account number
- **AMIID1** and **AMIID2** are two AMIIDs
- **RESTRICTED_VPCID** is VPC ID that you want to restrict.

Comment: I tried as per above policy, its not giving me desired results. With this policy i am able to launch ec2 with any AMI even in restricted VPC.